# Select checkbox to email items

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, outlook

I have checkboxes and items in the sheet and I want to email items when the checkboxes are selected.

I have this error

> Subscript out of range

Spreadsheet I'm testing on:
[image: This is the image of the spreadsheet that Im testing on]

```vb
Private Sub sendEmail(arrType, arrItem, arrQuantity, arrUnit)

    Dim i      As Integer
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("outlook.application"
    Dim ws     As Worksheet
    Dim strSubject As String
    Dim strBody As String
    Dim strType As String
    Dim strItem As String
    Dim strQuantity As String
    Dim strUnit As String
    Dim strTable As String
    Dim strHTML As String
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    
    strSubject = "Testing"
    strBody = "<html>"
    strBody = strBody & "Please see the order details below for your reference:<br><br>"
    strTable = "<br><table border = 2><tbody>"
    strTable = strTable & "<tr>"
    strTable = strTable & "<th align = center> Type</th>"
    strTable = strTable & "<th align = center> Item</th>"
    strTable = strTable & "<th align = center> Quantity</th>"
    strTable = strTable & "<th align = center> unit</th>"
    strTable = strTable & "<tr/>"
    
    For i = 4 To UBound(arrType)
        strType = arrType(i)
        strItem = arrItem(i)
        strQuantity = arrQuantity(i)
        strUnit = arrUnit(i)
        
        strTable = strTable & "<tr><td>" & strType & "</td>"
        strTable = strTable & "<td>" & strItem & "</td>"
        strTable = strTable & "<td>" & strQuantity & "</td>"
        strTable = strTable & "<td>" & strUnit & "</td></tr>"
    Next
    strTable = strTable & "</tbody></table><br>"
    strHTML = strBody & strTable & "</html>"
    
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to submit? ", vbYesNo, "Submit Confirmation") = vbYes Then
        Dim objEmail As Object
        Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
        With objEmail
            .To = ""
            .Subject = "testing"
            .HTMLBody = strHTML
            .Display
            .Send
        End With
        MsgBox "Thanks for the order. Your order details are sent successfully.", vbxOKOnly, "Operation Successful"
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub itemStored(arrType, arrItem, arrQuantity, arrUnit)

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    
    Dim i      As Long
    Dim cb     As CheckBox
    
    For Each cb In CheckBoxes
        If cb.Value = 1 Then
            arrType(i) = ws.Cells(i + 4, "I").Value
            arrItem(i) = ws.Cells(i + 4, "I").Value
            arrQuantity(i) = ws.Cells(i + 4, "I").Value
            arrUnit(i) = ws.Cells(i + 4, "I").Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub

Private Sub cmdbtnShow_Click()
    OrderForm.Show
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim arrType() As Variant
    Dim arrItem() As Variant
    Dim arrQuantity As Integer
    Dim arrUnit As String

    Call itemStored(arrType, arrItem, arrQuantity, arrUnit)
    Call sendEmail(arrType, arrItem, arrQuantity, arrUnit)
End Sub
```

When the checkboxes are selected, items on the left hand side will send an email. I tried making arrType and arrItem correspond to sendEmail.

Comment: There's no worksheet "Data" in the workbook where your code is running?  If that's not it then you need to tell us *which line* is throwing that error.  Also, you have not sized any of those arrays you're passing around - that could also lead to the same error.  And you're sourcing all the array values from the same column.

Comment: Then the problem is you've not sized your arrays.  You need to do that before trying to add any items to them.

Comment: `For Each cb In CheckBoxes` - where are these checkboxes?  It's not clear where the code you posted is - in a worksheet code module?  A regular module?  What is on the form you show?

Comment: ```For i = 4 To UBound(arrType)```
This line of code is getting an error. Also the worksheet "Data" is my excel workbook. How do I size the arrays?

Comment: Typically something like (eg) `Dim arrType(0 to 10)`

Comment: `arrQuantity` and `arrUnit` are not declared as arrays

Comment: What type of checkboxes are they?  Forms, or ActiveX ?

Comment: I just uploaded the image, hope you see it. It shows the checkboxes on the right and the items on the left. The code is in a worksheet code module. The type of checkboxes are activeX

Comment: Do I put like ```Dim arrQuantity As New ArrayList``` and ```Dim arrUnit As New ArrayList```?

Comment: `ArrayList` is not a VBA thing...

Comment: ```Dim arrType(0 - 100) As Variant
    Dim arrItem(0 - 100) As Variant
    Dim arrQuantity As Integer
    Dim arrUnit(0 - 100) As String```
is this right? because quantity is supposed to be a digit so i put integer instead of arrays

Comment: You still need to be able to collect multiple values for quantity though...  Anyway - see my slightly different approach below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out - I think it's easier to use a collection of arrays to hold information from the selected rows.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub sendEmail(colItems As Collection)

    Dim objOutlook As Object, arr, ws As Worksheet, objEmail As Object
    Dim i As Integer, strSubject As String, strBody As String, strTable As String, strHTML As String
    
    strSubject = "Testing"
    strBody = "<html>"
    strBody = strBody & "Please see the order details below for your reference:<br><br>"
    strTable = "<table border=2><tbody>"
    strTable = strTable & "<tr><th align='center'>Type</th>"
    strTable = strTable & "<th align='center'>Item</th>"
    strTable = strTable & "<th align='center'>Quantity</th>"
    strTable = strTable & "<th align='center'>unit</th></tr>"
    For Each arr In colItems 'loop arrays in collection
        strTable = strTable & "<tr><td>" & Join(arr, "</td><td>") & "</td></tr>"
    Next arr
    strTable = strTable & "</tbody></table>"
    strHTML = strBody & strTable & "<br></html>"
    
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to submit? ", vbYesNo, "Submit Confirmation") = vbYes Then
        
        Set objOutlook = CreateObject("outlook.application")
        Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
        With objEmail
            .To = ""
            .Subject = strSubject
            .HTMLBody = strHTML
            .Display
            '.send
        End With
        MsgBox "Thanks for the order. Your order details are sent successfully.", _
               vbOKOnly, "Operation Successful"
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub

'collect information from each row associated with a checked ActiveX checkbox...
Private Function selectedItems() As Collection
    Dim obj As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Set selectedItems = New Collection
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    For Each obj In ws.OLEObjects   'loop all controls on the sheet
        If TypeName(obj.Object) = "CheckBox" Then 'is a checkbox?
            If obj.Object.Value = True Then       'checkbox is checked?
                With obj.TopLeftCell.EntireRow    'the row the checkbox is on
                    'add array of row values to the collection
                    selectedItems.Add Array(.Columns("D").Value, .Columns("E").Value, _
                                            .Columns("F").Value, .Columns("G").Value)
                End With
            End If 'checked
        End If
    Next obj
End Function

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim selItems As Collection
    Set selItems = selectedItems() 'returns a Collection of arrays
    If selItems.Count > 0 Then
        sendEmail selItems
    Else
        MsgBox "No items selected"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks and it works. How do I include the total at the end of the quantity column tho?

Comment: Create the total as you loop over the collection to create the table.  Give it a try